# Getting the Source channel of a call from Asterisk

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami

I am developing a CTI Client for Asterisk, and handling one extension at a time.
When a call is coming, I can get all the details but the channel of source phone. I have seen the Dial event gives the Source Channel. But As I am not handling the Source Phone (Using Proxy), I am not getting events from Source Phone. How can I get it. Please Help!..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your dialplan

```
 exten => s,n,UserEvent(ParentChannel,${BRIDGEDPEER})
```

For more info see

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+UserEvent

Also you can do DumpChan to see all variable on channel any time in your asterisk console

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+DumpChan